# Наведение курсора на ячейку таблицы JS

Tags: javascript

Как при наведении на ячейку таблицы с числами в JS подсветить еще например 3 ячейки, близких по значению к основной?
Меня интересует не готовое решение, а подход как сделать.

```
  function matrix(m, n, x) {
  const table = document.createElement('table');
  const arr = [];
  const colAvg = [];
  const sumArr = [];
  const changeValues = (i, j) => {
    console.log(i, j)
    sumArr[i] += 1;
    arr[i][j] += 1;
    const columns = arr[i][j];
      for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
        var columnTotal = 0
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          columnTotal += arr[i][j]
        }
        colAvg[j] = columnTotal / arr.length
      }
    console.log(sumArr)
    console.log(arr[i][j])
    console.log(colAvg)
    document.getElementById(i + "-" + j).textContent = arr[i][j];
    document.getElementsByClassName('sumChange')[i].textContent = sumArr[i];
    document.getElementsByClassName('Avg')[j].textContent = colAvg[j];
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    colAvg[j] = 0;
    var sumCol = 0;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    arr[i] = [];
    var summM = 0;

    for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.id = + i + "-" + j;
      td.className = "plusOne";
      td.textContent = arr[i][j] = getRandom();
      td.onclick = function () {
        changeValues(i, j);
      } 
      td.onmouseover = function () {
        var target = event.target;
        target.style.background = '#8888FF';
      };
      td.onmouseout = function () {
        var target = event.target;
        target.style.background = '';
      };
      tr.appendChild(td);
      summM += arr[i][j];
      colAvg[j] += arr[i][j] / colAvg.length;
    }

      for (var j = 0; j < 1 ; j++) {
        td = document.createElement('td');
        td.className = "sumChange";
        td.textContent = summM;
        tr.appendChild(td);
        sumArr.push(summM);

  }
    table.appendChild(tr);
    console.log(tr)
    console.log(sumArr)
  }

  tr = document.createElement('tr');
  for (var j = 0; j < n ; j++) {
    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.className = "Avg";
    td.textContent = colAvg[j];
    tr.appendChild(td);
    colAvg;
    }

  table.appendChild(tr);
  console.log(colAvg)

  console.log(tr)
  console.log(arr)


  document.getElementById('myTable').appendChild(table);

  function getRandom() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 900 + 99);
  }

}
matrix(4, 4, 4);
```

Comment: А как подсветить хотя бы ту ячейку, над которой курсор?

Comment: td.onmouseover = function () {
        var target = event.target;
        target.style.background = '#8888FF';
      };
      td.onmouseout = function () {
        var target = event.target;
        target.style.background = '';
      };
Я так сделал.

Comment: Добавьте код к вопросу.

Comment: @js_new Я обновил мой ответ рабочим примером

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Определяете критерий "близкие по значению".
- При наведении на ячейку берете её значение и сравниваете со значениями в остальных ячейках. Если используете `jQuery`, то `jQuery.filter()` то, что нужно.
- Всем найденным ячейкам присваиваете класс, по котому они подсвечиваются.
- При уходе с ячейки - удаляете класс подсветки со всех элементов

### Добавлено

Задачка усложняется возможностью наличия одинаковых чисел в таблице. В этом случае следует ещё считать расстояние от ячейки.

Ниже и на [codepen](https://codepen.io/nsmcan/pen/NmgJKd) - полный рабочий код.
Я постарался добавить комментариев по-максимуму

```js
function matrix(m, n, x) {
    const table = document.createElement('table');
    const arr = [];
    const values = {};
    const colAvg = [];
    const sumArr = [];
    const changeValues = (i, j) => {
        console.log(i, j)
        sumArr[i] += 1;
        arr[i][j] += 1;
        const columns = arr[i][j];
        for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            var columnTotal = 0
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                columnTotal += arr[i][j]
            }
            colAvg[j] = columnTotal / arr.length
        }
        console.log(sumArr)
        console.log(arr[i][j])
        console.log(colAvg)
        document.getElementById(i + "-" + j).textContent = arr[i][j];
        document.getElementsByClassName('sumChange')[i].textContent = sumArr[i];
        document.getElementsByClassName('Avg')[j].textContent = colAvg[j];
    }

    var numRandom = 4;
    var randomValues = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numRandom; i++) {
        randomValues.push(getRandom());
    }


    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        colAvg[j] = 0;
        var sumCol = 0;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        arr[i] = [];
        var summM = 0;

        for (let j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.id = + i + "-" + j;
            td.className = "plusOne";
            var value = randomValues[getRandomInt(0, numRandom-1)];

            td.textContent = arr[i][j] = value;
            values[value] = values[value] || [];
            values[value].push({ 'i': i, 'j': j });

            td.onclick = function () {
                changeValues(i, j);
            }
            td.onmouseover = function onMoOv() {
                var target = event.target;
                target.style.background = '#8888FF';
                var targetI, targetJ;
                [targetI, targetJ] = target.id.split('-').map(x => + x); //Get coordinates from ID
                var value = + target.textContent;
                var index = valuesSorted.indexOf(value); //Position of the selected value in the list of sorted values
                var closest = [ value ]; //List of the closest values. Initialized with the selected value
                var closestQty = values[value].length; //Quantity of cells with the closest values. Note, several cells could have the same value
                var i = index - 1, j = index + 1; //Positions before and after index
                var delta = 0; //Current delta between values
                var deltaPrev = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; //delta between selected value and a value before it in the list of sorted values
                var deltaNext = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; //delta between selected value and a value after it in the list of sorted values
                var valuePrev, valueNext; //current values before and after selected in the list of sorted values
                var valueToAdd;
                while (closestQty < x+1) {
                    //Checking values from the sorted list - before of the selected value
                    if (i >= 0) {
                        valuePrev = valuesSorted[i];
                        deltaPrev = value - valuePrev;
                    } else {
                        deltaPrev = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; //Reset delta value
                    }

                    //Checking values from the sorted list - after the selected value
                    if (j < valuesSorted.length) {
                        valueNext = valuesSorted[j];
                        deltaNext = valueNext - value;
                    }
                    else {
                        deltaNext = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; //Reset delta value
                    }

                    //Taking one with a smaller delta
                    if (deltaPrev < deltaNext) {
                        valueToAdd = valuePrev;
                        i--;
                    } else {
                        valueToAdd = valueNext;
                        j++;
                    }

                    closest.push(valueToAdd);
                    closestQty += values[valueToAdd].length;
                }
                var closestValueIds = []; //IDs of cells we will be selecting
                var qty = 0; //Number of cells we found to be selected
                var k = 0; //Index in a list of the closest values
                while (qty < x + 1) {
                    value = closest[k];
                    if (x + 1 - qty >= values[value].length) {
                    //Number of cells with a given value less than current number of cells to select
                        for (var n = 0; n < values[value].length; n++) {
                            var coordinates = values[value][n];
                            closestValueIds.push(+ coordinates.i + "-" + coordinates.j);
                        }
                        qty += values[value].length;
                        k++;
                    } else {
                    //Calculate minimal distance between same value cells and selected cell
                        var distances = [];
                        for (var n = 0; n < values[value].length; n++) {
                            var coordinates = values[value][n];
                            var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(coordinates.i - targetI, 2) + Math.pow(coordinates.j - targetJ, 2));
                            distances.push({ 'distance': distance, 'id': + coordinates.i + "-" + coordinates.j });
                        }
                        distances.sort((a, b) => a.distance - b.distance);
                        for (var n = 0; n < distances.length; n++) {
                            closestValueIds.push(distances[n].id);
                            if (++qty == x + 1) { break; }
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < closestValueIds.length; i++) {
                    document.getElementById(closestValueIds[i]).classList.add('highlighted');
                }
            };
            td.onmouseout = function onMoOut() {
                var target = event.target;
                target.style.background = '';
                document.querySelectorAll('td.highlighted').forEach(el => el.classList.remove('highlighted'));
            };
            tr.appendChild(td);
            summM += arr[i][j];
            colAvg[j] += arr[i][j] / colAvg.length;

        }

        for (var j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
            td = document.createElement('td');
            td.className = "sumChange";
            td.textContent = summM;
            tr.appendChild(td);
            sumArr.push(summM);

        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
        console.log(tr)
        console.log(sumArr)
    }

    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        td = document.createElement('td');
        td.className = "Avg";
        td.textContent = colAvg[j];
        tr.appendChild(td);
        colAvg;
    }

    let valuesSorted = Object.keys(values).map(x => +x).sort();

    table.appendChild(tr);
    console.log(colAvg)

    console.log(tr)
    console.log(arr)


    document.getElementById('myTable').appendChild(table);

    function getRandom() {
        return Math.round(Math.random() * 900 + 99);
    }

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        min = Math.ceil(min);
        max = Math.floor(max);
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
}

matrix(4, 4, 4);
```

```css
table td {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.sumChange {
 background: #0a55ce;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.Avg {
 background: #0a55ce;
 color: #ffffff;
}
.highlighted {
 background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="myTable"></table>
 
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Array​.prototype​.filter() этот метод используется вместо jQuery.filter()?
Числа генерируются рандомно. 
Близкие по значению - это например есть массив чисел [165, 179, 161, 198, 231, 256]  я навёл курсор на число 161 и ближайшие 3 числа к нему это 198, 179, 165.

Comment: @js_new Проблема в Вашем вопросе - это простыня недокументированного кода. Я даже не пытался его расшифровать, отвечая на вопрос. Сейчас посмотрел с утра на свежую голову. Так и не нашёл, что такое параметр `x`. Для чистого javascript мне нужно посмотреть получше, так как Вам нужен поиск элементов. Хотя, имея массив значений, можно искать ближайшие в нем, а затем искать искать элементы по точным значениям

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mgwzNy
Параметр х это количество ячеек ближайшие к той на которую навели курсор.

Comment: @js_new Я сделал решение для hover. Для случая, когда Вы меняете значение в ячейке по клику - добавьте блок, пересчитывающий объект values и массив valuesSorted